# Access repository or service from entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot to write server application.

Most of the time, I write all business logic inside services, where I use `@Autowired` to access repositories and other services.

However, sometimes I want to access certain service or property from `@Entity` class, which cannot use `@Autowired`.

For instance, I have an entity that should be able to serialize itself to JSON. In JSON, it should have imageUrl field, which contains of image name (stored in database and as a property in the `@Entity` class) and base url, which is only available in application.properties. This means that I have to use `@Value` annotation inside `@Entity` class, but it doesn't work that way.

So I create a service which looks like this:

```
@Service
public class FilesService {

    private static FilesService instance;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        FilesService.instance = this;
    }

    public static FilesService getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Value("${files.path}")
    String filesPath;
    @Value("${files.url}")
    String filesUrl;

    public String saveFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        if (file == null || file.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        String filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        file.transferTo(new File(filesPath + filename));
        return filename;
    }

    public String getFileUrl(String filename) {
        if (filename == null || filename.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return filesUrl + filename;
    }

}
```

And then inside the `@Entity` class I write the following code:

```
@JsonProperty
public String getImageUrl() {
    return FilesService.getInstance().getFileUrl(imageName);
}
```

This works, but it doesn't look right. Moreover, I concern whether this can lead to some side effects if used with less trivial `@Service` classes or `@Repository` classes.

What is the correct way to use `@Repository` and `@Service` classes from `@Entity` classes or any other non-`@Component` classes (classes not managed by Spring)?

Comment: Why don't you store the url along in that entity too? When the client/controller creates a new entity the file path can be passed to your entity. I know there's no set rule' but it 'feels' wrong to have that hidden dependency in your entity.

Comment: Well, ntot service. Write custom marshaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd say there's no correct way of using repositories and services from entities since every fiber of my being screams of wrongness but that being said , you can refer to [this link](https://guylabs.ch/2014/02/22/autowiring-pring-beans-in-hibernate-jpa-entity-listeners/) for suggestions on how to do it.

In your case, I think it should allow you to populate `@Value` fields within your entities, which would actually be preferable to autowiring the service.